# Build BST with an array and query a new node insertion level/depth

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

I am trying to build a BST based on an array.
my question is once I have a new value (TreeNode value) and want to insert it into my bst, and return the level of this TreeNode after its insertion. is there a (quick) way to know its level/depth information? Moreover, is there a way to know its level without actually build the BST. For example, I have an array [3,1,2], and I want to insert 4, is there a way to know what is the depth/level of 4 without actually build the BST and search for 4 to get is depth?
Thank you.
(If you don't mind, python code is preferred. sorry for any inconvenience.)

Comment: I presume you want a balanced BST? Otherwise the question is a bit trivial. But for a self-balancing tree, the actual structure after insertion will depend on which particular self-balancing BST data structure you use (and which order you insert elements in).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you mind sharing one structure you recommend and how to implement the insertion based on the structure you proposed? I am also wondering if add a node.level attribute to TreeNode class would be helpful ?

Answer (score 0):

A complete BST has 2^k-1 nodes for some k>0. The k-bit binary fractions between 0 and 1 (not inclusive) listed in ascending order with trailing zeros removed serve as "instructions" for deciding where to place each node in the sorted list.  For example, if k=3, then the tree has 7 nodes. The binary fractions are

```
001
01
011
1
101
11
111
```

Now suppose the sorted list to be placed in the tree is [10,20,30,40,50,60,70]. Interpret a 0 to mean "go left: and every 1 except the final one to mean "go right."  The final 1 means "stop here."  We start at the root.  The match-up is

```
001 <-> 10
01  <-> 20
011 <-> 30
1   <-> 40
101 <-> 50
11  <-> 60
111 <-> 70
```

Following the "instructions", you'll end up with the list elements in the tree as follows:

```
            40
        20      60
     10   30  50  70
```

Voila! A BST. This works for all `k`.  Proving why is an interesting task! I will leave it to you to turn this observation into a working algorithm. There are several ways to do that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I will try to understand and do the implementation. Hope you don't mind if I ask follow up question to you if I get stuck somewhere during my applying the algorithm.